# Regex for finding the name of a method containing a string

Tags: regex, node-modules, abstract-syntax-tree

I've got a Node module file containing about 100 exported methods, which looks something like this:

```js
exports.methodOne = async user_id => {
    // other method contents
};
exports.methodTwo = async user_id => {
    // other method contents
    fooMethod();
};
exports.methodThree = async user_id => {
    // other method contents
    fooMethod();
};
```

**Goal**: What I'd like to do is figure out how to grab the name of any method which contains a call to `fooMethod`, and return the correct method names: methodTwo and methodThree. I wrote a regex which gets *kinda close*:

```regex
exports\.(\w+).*(\n.*?){1,}fooMethod
```

**Problem**: using my example code from above, though, it would effectively match methodOne and methodThree because it finds the first instance of `export` and then the first instance of `fooMethod` and goes on from there. [Here's a regex101 example](https://regex101.com/r/E4CdOE/1).

I suspect I could make use of lookaheads or lookbehinds, but I have little experience with those parts of regex, so any guidance would be much appreciated!

---

**Edit**: Turns out regex is poorly-suited for this type of task. @ctcherry advised using a parser, and using that as a springboard, I was able to learn about Abstract Syntax Trees (ASTs) and the [recast](https://github.com/benjamn/recast) tool which lets you traverse the tree after using various tools ([acorn](https://github.com/acornjs/acorn) and others) to parse your code into tree form.

With these tools in hand, I successfully built a script to parse and traverse my node app's files, and was able to find all methods containing `fooMethod` as intended.

Comment: You selected PCRE2 option in the regex101 fiddle, what is the actual environment where you are using this regex?

Comment: Hi @WiktorStribiżew! PCRE2 is the default option in regex101; I didn't actively pick it. That said, if regex is poorly-suited to handle this sort of situation, as others have pointed out below, I'd be completely open to any solution which yields the results I mentioned under my "Goal".

Initially, I tried using `ripgrep` to get what I wanted, but as I showed, my regex was a bit off, so it didn't pan out. Happy to re-word the question / title if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex isn't the best tool to tackle all the parts of this problem, ideally we could rely on something higher level, a parser.

One way to do this is to let the javascript parse itself during load and execution. If your node module doesn't include anything that would execute on its own (or at least anything that would conflict with the below), you can put this at the bottom of your module, and then run the module with `node mod.js`.

```
console.log(Object.keys(exports).filter(fn => exports[fn].toString().includes("fooMethod(")));
```

(In the comments below it is revealed that the above isn't possible.)

Another option would be to use a library like https://github.com/acornjs/acorn (there are other options) to write some other javascript that parses your original target javascript, then you would have a tree structure you could use to perform your matching and eventually return the function names you are after. I'm not an expert in that library so unfortunately I don't have sample code for you.

Comment: Hey @ctcherry, unfortunately the module _does_ have a bunch of elements which run / call things that execute on their own and disallow the file from being run in isolation...

Comment: Gotcha, yeah that will be a problem, I've updated my answer here with an alternative

Answer (score 1):

This regex matches (only) the method names that contain a call to `fooMethod();`

```
(?<=exports\.)\w+(?=[^{]+\{[^}]+fooMethod\(\)[^}]+};)
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/1tf8hRGErt6bZr).

Comment: wouldn't it fail if the function included `{}` like in conditional blocks or loops before `fooMethod();`

Comment: @K450 yes, it would fail. Regex is not a substitute for a parser. For the examples given, this works.

Comment: Agreed. Btw is it possible to match only if it encounters `fooMethod();` before next occurrence of `exports.` and fail if its other way around, like is there way to implement it with lookarounds and how, will it solve the issue?

Comment: @K450 Depends on the language/tool. Some (uncommon) support `\K` for recursive matching, but in general “no”. Consider also a string like `str = 'fooMethod();'`. There’s a lot of ways that valid code can defeat a regex. To be sure, you need a parser. If you’re willing to set reasonable guardrails, regex will work for you.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that all methods have their body enclosed within `{` and `}`, I would make an approach to get to the final regex like this:

- First, find a regex to get the individual methods. This can be done using this regex:

```
exports\.(\w+)(\s|.)*?\{(\s|.)*?\}
```

- Next, we are interested in those methods that have `fooMethod` in them **before they close**. So, look for `}` or `fooMethod.*}`, in that order. So, let us name the group searching for `fooMethod` as `FOO` and the name of the method calling it as `METH`. When we iterate the matches, if group `FOO` is present in a match, we will use the corresponding `METH` group, else we will reject it.

```
exports\.(?<METH>\w+)(\s|.)*?\{(\s|.)*?(\}|(?<FOO>fooMethod)(\s|.)*?\})
```

**Explanation:**

- `exports\.(?<METH>\w+)`: Till the method name (you have already covered this)
- `(\s|.)*?\{(\s|.)*?`: Some code before `{` and after, non-greedy so that the subsequent group is given preference
- `(\}|(?<FOO>fooMethod)(\s|.)*?\})`: This has 2 parts:

  - `\}`: Match the method close delimiter, OR
  - `(?<FOO>fooMethod)(\s|.)*?\})`: The call to `fooMethod` followed by optional code and method close delimiter.

Here's a JavaScript code that demostrates this:

```js
let p = /exports\.(?<METH>\w+)(\s|.)*?\{(\s|.)*?(\}|(?<FOO>fooMethod)(\s|.)*?\})/g
let input = `exports.methodOne = async user_id => {
    // other method contents
};
exports.methodTwo = async user_id => {
    // other method contents
    fooMethod();
};
exports.methodThree = async user_id => {
    // other method contents
    fooMethod();
};';`
let match = p.exec( input );
while( match !== null) {
    if( match.groups.FOO !== undefined ) console.log( match.groups.METH );
    match = p.exec( input )
}
```

Comment: `(\s|.)*?` should never be used in any regex flavor (other than ElasticSearch) (see why in [this YT video of mine](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SEobSs-ZCSE&t=1s)). Please replace with the proper `[^]` (for JavaScript/ECMAScript) or `.` with `s` flag (`m` flag for Ruby/Onigmo) or one of the ~universal workarounds (`[\s\S]` / `[\d\D]` / `[\w\W]`).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, Thanks for pointing out. Went through your video as well. I will try to come up with the alternative form.